# How to implement a dropdown subpage show detailed information when clicking a picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to implement an inpage shopping cart. When you click a picture of a product, the webpage shows detailed information of that product.

Here's what Google Image Search does:

[Google Image Search http://www.wy19900814fun.com/thumbnails/test.png](http://www.wy19900814fun.com/thumbnails/test.png)

When you click an image, the detailed information of that picture will show below that picture (It's not at the bottom of the screen).

And here's my code. Someone helped me yesterday so that when I click a picture, some info could show below that picture.

But I want the whole `<div class='container'>` to show beneath that picture (including that picture and all the information, although they are the same currently).

I think the problem is definitely in the JQuery script.

P.S. There's also some layout problems when you click second line of pictures, there might be only one or two pics in one line. I don't know why, I hope to get some help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('img').click(function() {
    var $img = $(this),
        offset = $img.offset(),
        subPage = $('.container').hide().insertAfter('.pictures'),
        nextImage = $img.next(),
        finalImage = $img;
  
    if (!$img.is(':last-child')) {
       while (offset.top == nextImage.offset().top) {
          nextImage = nextImage.next();
       }
    
       finalImage = nextImage.prev();
    }
    
    subPage.html('').append($img.clone()).insertAfter(finalImage).slideDown();
 });
});
```

```css
    .pictures{
  text-align:center;
 }
 .pictures img{
  display:inline-block;
        width:200px;
 }
 .container{
  text-align:center;
 }
  
 .left-container{
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px;
 }
 .left-container img{
  
 }
  
 .right-container{
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px;
 }
  
 .color-group{
  text-align:center;
 }
 .color-group ul{
     padding:0;
 }
 .color-group li{
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="pictures">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20964301401_5d9fdf5c0d_o_large_958fe482-f2e7-4120-b4fe-016fcf612bf5_large.jpeg?v=1440873580">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20770321799_5c81882577_o_large_c4c19c91-0532-422f-99d0-297b2731c4e3_large.jpeg?v=1440873580">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17108089939_8d4cefd10a_o_large_3dc1d49b-cb59-432a-a8d7-b118cfd61314_large.jpeg?v=1440873578">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17950190230_114070818c_o_large_60ce5c71-7575-49ab-be75-ed2cfed6768d_large.jpeg?v=1440873577">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15175737319_c0db73446f_o_zps867eecb9_large_858814b0-6a80-4a34-b55d-97acc179cc91_large.jpeg?v=1440873576">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085342999_b8878e538e_o_zps54a2d381_large_f731cd55-f8d0-4e9a-8ba5-c254b4b8241d_large.jpeg?v=1440873575">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085523427_bacc983407_o_zps2c262937_large.jpeg?v=1440873574">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15268975561_ed3f9f5c0b_o_zpsd4857119_large.jpeg?v=1440873573">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15339485796_bed118ac3c_o_zpsf0927ac3_large.jpeg?v=1440873572">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/IMG_9092_zpsc38bd27c_large.jpeg?v=1440873571">
 </div>
 
 
 <div class = 'container'>
  <div class = 'left-container'>
   <img class='subpage-pic' src='http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0964/6944/products/10_large.jpg?v=1441133119'>
  </div>
  
  <div class = 'right-container'>
   <h1>Green Leaf</h1>
   <h3>Mari</h3>
   <h5>Category, vendor needed?</h5>
   <p>This is the description of Green Leaf case, just in case, I make it a little bit longer, testetstestsetsetsetsetsetsettsetsets</p>
   <p>$19.99</p>
   <select>
      <option value ="volvo">Iphone 6</option>
      <option value ="saab">Iphone 6+</option>
      <option value="opel">Samsung 6S</option>
      <option value="audi">Iphone 5</option>
   </select>
   <div class = 'color-group'>
    <ul>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:green;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:gray;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:yellow;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:red;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:blue;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:#FF00DD;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <Button>ADD TO CART</Button>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: I've adjusted the text of your question slightly. It is important not to give the impression that you'd like someone to set up your code on their machine and do all the necessary development for you! `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you, by changing the JQuery code, I go the answer.

One is .slideToggle, another is .attr

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.test').click(function() {
  var $img = $(this).children('img'),
        subPage = $('.container');
        $('.subpage-pic').attr("src", $img.attr("src"));
        
        var offset = $img.offset(),
        nextImage = $img.next(),
        finalImage = $img;
  
    if (!$img.is(':last-child')) {
  while (offset.top == nextImage.offset().top) {
          nextImage = nextImage.next();
       }
    
       finalImage = nextImage.prev();
    }
    
  subPage.insertAfter(finalImage).slideToggle('fast');
 });
 });
```

```css
.pictures{
   text-align:center;
  }
  .pictures img{
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .container{
   text-align:center;
   display:none;
  }
  
  .left-container{
   vertical-align:middle;
   display:inline-block;
   border-style: solid;
       border-width: 5px;
  }
  .left-container img{
   
  }
  
  .right-container{
   vertical-align:middle;
   display:inline-block;
   border-style: solid;
       border-width: 5px;
  }
  
  .color-group{
   text-align:center;
  }
  .color-group ul{
       padding:0;
  }
  .color-group li{
   width:20px;
   display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'container'>
  <div class = 'left-container'>
   <img class='subpage-pic' src='http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0964/6944/products/10_large.jpg?v=1441133119'>
  </div>
  
  <div class = 'right-container'>
   <h1>Green Leaf</h1>
   <h3>Mari</h3>
   <h5>Category, vendor needed?</h5>
   <p>This is the description of Green Leaf case, just in case, I make it a little bit longer, testetstestsetsetsetsetsetsettsetsets</p>
   <p>$19.99</p>
   <select>
      <option value ="volvo">Iphone 6</option>
      <option value ="saab">Iphone 6+</option>
      <option value="opel">Samsung 6S</option>
      <option value="audi">Iphone 5</option>
   </select>
   <div class = 'color-group'>
    <ul>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:green;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:gray;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:yellow;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:red;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:blue;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li style="background-size:cover; background-color:#FF00DD;"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <Button>ADD TO CART</Button>
  </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="pictures">
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20964301401_5d9fdf5c0d_o_large_958fe482-f2e7-4120-b4fe-016fcf612bf5_large.jpeg?v=1440873580"></div>
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20770321799_5c81882577_o_large_c4c19c91-0532-422f-99d0-297b2731c4e3_large.jpeg?v=1440873580"></div>
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17108089939_8d4cefd10a_o_large_3dc1d49b-cb59-432a-a8d7-b118cfd61314_large.jpeg?v=1440873578"></div>
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17950190230_114070818c_o_large_60ce5c71-7575-49ab-be75-ed2cfed6768d_large.jpeg?v=1440873577"></div>
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15175737319_c0db73446f_o_zps867eecb9_large_858814b0-6a80-4a34-b55d-97acc179cc91_large.jpeg?v=1440873576"></div>
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085342999_b8878e538e_o_zps54a2d381_large_f731cd55-f8d0-4e9a-8ba5-c254b4b8241d_large.jpeg?v=1440873575"></div>
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085523427_bacc983407_o_zps2c262937_large.jpeg?v=1440873574"></div>
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15268975561_ed3f9f5c0b_o_zpsd4857119_large.jpeg?v=1440873573"></div>
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15339485796_bed118ac3c_o_zpsf0927ac3_large.jpeg?v=1440873572"></div>
  <div class='test'><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/IMG_9092_zpsc38bd27c_large.jpeg?v=1440873571"></div>
 </div>
```